# "После нашей свадьбы" - какой член предложения?

Tags: синтаксис, определения

> Через несколько дней после нашей свадьбы мы отправились путешествовать.

После нашей свадьбы - какой член предложения? Можно ли его считать несогласованным определением? Помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Через несколько дней **после нашей свадьбы** мы отправились путешествовать.*

*Через несколько дней после нашей свадьбы* – это обстоятельство со значением времени, в состав которого входит **обстоятельственное определение** *после нашей свадьбы*  (несогласованное определение, выраженное падежной формой существительного).

Пояснение

1. Как решаются такие задачи **в общем виде?** Для себя выбрала два критерия: (1) надо обязательно учитывать тот **вопрос**, который мы задаем в нашей естественной речи (иногда это два вопроса);  2) нужно использовать **теорию,** которая изложена в виде системы в каком-нибудь  авторитетном источнике (меня вполне устраивает вузовский учебник Кустовой (стр. 77 – 81).
2. Сочетание «после нашей свадьбы» относится к существительному, и мы можем задать уточняющий вопрос (когда именно?). Это обстоятельство времени? Но в учебник сказано, что «обстоятельство — это второстепенный член предложения, который относится к слову со значением **действия или признака**».
3. У нас же падежная форма относится **к существительному**. Тогда это определение с добавочным обстоятельственным значением.

Из учебника:  «У несогласованных определений значение признака **осложняется** другими значениями (во многих случаях добавочное значение можно установить по той конструкции, с которой соотносится определение). В том числе добавочными могут быть **обстоятельственные** значения».

4. Вывод: ***после нашей свадьбы***  – это обстоятельственное определение.
   [https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)

Comment: Sharon, Ваш ответ прекрасен! Тема для меня прояснилась! Спасибо Вам!)

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв.

Answer (score 2):

«После нашей свадьбы» — это обстоятельство времени.

Comment: Вопросы: Через несколько дней после нашей свадьбы – это сложное обстоятельство? Или у вас два обстоятельства времени подряд? 
Но в любом случае отношения между ними неоднородные, судя  по отсутствию запятой?  Но неоднородные обстоятельства характеризуют действие с разных сторон, а что это здесь значит? Это вопросы не только к вам, но и к голосующим за вас тоже. Поясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Заниматься тонкими вопросами определения членов предложения — мартышкин труд. Когда-то давно люди ввели крайне полезную грубую классификацию слов по функции, которую эти слова выполняют в предложении. Во многих предложениях был некий деятель и действие, подвергаемый воздействию объект, характеристики объекта и деятеля и условия, при которых происходило действие. Но как и в любой классификации есть множества ситуаций, которые не разрешаются общими классифицирующими правилами.

Comment: Например, в предложении, где подлежащее — инфинитив: «Верить лжецу бесполезно», следует ли из чего-то, что «верить» — подлежащее? Обычно у нас есть деятель и действие, а тут уже подлежащее — инфинитив. Это ни из чего не следует, а является просто результатом договоренности, мы условились так считать. Тут вопрос в том, какая вообще польза от всего этого, если это просто результат договоренностей. На самом деле особой пользы нет.

Comment: Только если вам нужно сдать тестирование по этому вопросу, но тогда грамотеям следовало бы условится по поводу всех этих тонких ситуаций и выпустить учебник, где все эти ситуации детально описываются. Вместо этого они делают вид, что занимаются каким-то научным исследованием и выпускают кучу книг на адовом канцелярите. Возвращаясь к вопросу, как же нам разрешить ситуацию с оборотом: «Через несколько дней после нашей свадьбы»? Оба сочетания обозначают время события: одно — после чего произошло, другое — сколько времени прошлом.

Comment: Является ли «после нашей свадьбы» каким то супер редким видом определения, которое вывела госпожа Кустова? Да мне вообще п... .

Comment: Jim Korbett, очень эмоционально! Вашу энергию хорошо бы использовать в мирных целях – к примеру, преобразовать в электрическую и заряжать мобильные телефоны. Но надо научиться управлять ею. Что вас так возбудило, предложение или слово какое? Идея, может быть? Пальчиком не покажете? Мне кажется, что это протест натурального ума против невыносимого ига цивилизации. Конкретное мнение по поводу выступления я выскажу позже.

Comment: Кстати, а еще никто не хочет взять слово? Здесь любопытный психологический момент в части того, как проголосовало общество. Вопрос не получил ни одного голоса – он неинтересен? Мой ответ не получил ни одного голоса (пока не был принят) – он неправилен?  Первый ответ получил два голоса – это правильный и образцовый ответ? Хотелось бы услышать мнение как всего коллектива, так и тех двух участников, которые голосовали за этот ответ. Может быть, поясните свою точку зрения тоже?

Comment: Через несколько дней (каких?), прошедших после после нашей свадьбы, мы отправились путешествовать.  Определение, однако, не обстоятельство. Ваш ход, дорогой товарищ.

Comment: Нет, потому что можно переставить местами: «После нашей свадьбы через несколько дней мы отправились путешествовать». Как вы можете доказать, что здесь невидимый член(пропущенный в неполном предложении)? Никак!

Comment: Тогда нужно обособлять, если тут невидимый член и определительный оборот. Обособления нет — определительного оборота нет.

Comment: Неубедительно, ответ не принят. Одинаковое смысловое содержание может иметь синонимичные грамматические формы. Это же классика! Госпожа Кустова вам ясно сказала: определение с дополнительным обстоятельственным значением времени. Партия пока за мной.

Comment: Я понятия не имею, что такое «синонимичные грамматические формы».  Докажите, что «после нашей свадьбы» относится к «дней», а не к «мы отправились путешествовать».

Comment: Играть по вашим правилам и что-то вам доказывать я, разумеется,  не буду. Не слышали про синтаксическую синонимию?   Например, можно сказать: "горная дорога и дорога в горах", семантика здесь одинаковая, а грамматика разная. Вот как с вами серьезно разговаривать, если вы терминов не знаете. Поэтому не надо придавать форме большей значимости, чем она этого заслуживает – семантика важнее. А вы ничего не видите, кроме формы.  Думайте дальше – расширяйте сознание.

Comment: Я один раз слышал термин «синтаксический синоним», но не «синонимичные грамматические формы».

Comment: Это одно и то же.  Спасибо за участие, партия закончена, до новых встреч.